# Python/Flask - ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, flask

Before anyone says that this is a duplicate, I do not think it is because I have looked at the similar questions and they have not helped me!

I am creating a Flask server in python, and I need to be able to have a url that shows a pdf.

I tried to use the following code:

```
@app.route('/pdf')
def pdfStuff():

        with open('pdffile.pdf', 'rb') as static_file:
                return send_file(static_file, attachment_filename='pdffile.pdf')
```

This is supposed to make it so when I go to `/pdf` it will show the pdf file `pdffile.pdf`.

However, this does not work because when I run the code I get this error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

How is this the case? My return statement is inside the with statement, therefore shouldn't the file be open?

I tried to use a normal `static_file = open(...)` and used `try` and `finally` statements, like this:

```
static_file = open('pdffile.pdf','rb')
try:
        return send_file(static_file, attachment_filename='pdffile.pdf')
finally:
        static_file.close()
```

The same error happens with the above code, and I have no idea why. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Sorry if I am being stupid and there is something simple that I made a mistake with!

Thank you very much in advance !!

Comment: The context manager ensures the file gets closed before the function ends, you can't return the file handle that way.  Why not pass the file name instead?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that! I'll try that now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nice, it works! I didn't know you could pass the file name string instead of an actual file. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Use `send_file` with the filename, it'll open, serve and close it the way you expect.

```
@app.route('/pdf')
def pdfStuff():
    return send_file('pdffile.pdf')
```

Answer (score 5):

Despite @iurisilvio's answer solves this specific problem, **is not a useful answer in any other case.** I was struggling with this myself.

**All the following examples are throwing `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` but why?**

```py
@app.route('/pdf')
def pdfStuff():
    with open('pdffile.pdf', 'rb') as static_file:
        return send_file(static_file, attachment_filename='pdffile.pdf')


@app.route('/pdf')
def pdfStuff():
    static_file = open('pdffile.pdf','rb')
    try:
        return send_file(static_file, attachment_filename='pdffile.pdf')
    finally:
        static_file.close()
```

I am doing something slightly different. Like this:

```py
@page.route('/file', methods=['GET'])
def build_csv():

    # ... some query ...

    ENCODING = 'utf-8'
    bi = io.BytesIO()
    tw = io.TextIOWrapper(bi, encoding=ENCODING)
    c = csv.writer(tw)
    c.writerow(['col_1', 'col_2'])
    c.writerow(['1', '2'])

    bi.seek(0)
    return send_file(bi,
                     as_attachment=True,
                     attachment_filename='file.csv',
                     mimetype="Content-Type: text/html; charset={0}".format(ENCODING)
                     )
```

In the first two cases, the answer is simple:

You give a stream to `send_file`, this function will not immediatelly transmit the file, but rather wrap the stream and return it to Flask for future handling. Your `pdfStuff` function will allready return before Flask will start handling your stream, and in both cases (`with` and `finally`) the stream will be closed **before** your function returns.

The third case is more tricky (but this answer pointed me in the right direction: [Why is TextIOWrapper closing the given BytesIO stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434423/why-is-textiowrapper-closing-the-given-bytesio-stream)). In the same fashion as explained above, `bi` is handled only after `build_csv` returns. Hence `tw` has allready been abandoned to the garbage collector. When the collector will destroy it, `tw` will implicitly close `bi`. The solution to this one is `tw.detach()` before returning (this will stop `TextIOWrapper` from affecting the stream).

*Side note (please correct me if I'm wrong):
This behaviour is limiting, unless when `send_file` is provided with a file-like object it will handle the closing on its own. It is not clear from the documentation (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/api/#flask.send_file) if closing is handled. I would assume so (there are some `.close()` present in the source code + `send_file` uses `werkzeug.wsgi.FileWrapper` which has `.close()` implemented too), in which case your approach can be corrected to:*

```py
@app.route('/pdf')
def pdfStuff():
    return send_file(open('pdffile.pdf','rb'), attachment_filename='pdffile.pdf')
```

*Ofcourse in this case, would be stright forward to provide the file name. But in other cases, may be needed to wrap the file stream in some manipulation pipeline (decode / zip)*

Comment: I think you downvoted me. Your examples where my code doesn't work are broken by spec. You should not close the stream, WSGI will do that after it consumed the stream. I answered with the correct way to use `send_file`.

Comment: Yes I downvoted your answer, nothing personal. It is just due to your answer being simplistic in relation to the specific exception and send_file. As you know send file does support a file name or a file-like-object as input. And in the second case this exception is very common. I would like you to elaborate why you sustain my answer is wrong?