# How to write UTF-8 CSV into BytesIO in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, stringio

Firstly, I understand how to write UTF-8 from strings in Python3 and that `StringIO` is recommended for such string building. However, I specifically need a *binary* file-like object and for that I need `BytesIO`. If I do the following then the data ends up blowing up because it gets read as **Latin1**, my computer's default locale/charset.

```py
with io.StringIO() as sb:
    csv.writer(sb).writerows(rows)
    sb.flush()
    sb.seek(0)
    # blows up with Latin1 encoding error
    job = bq.load_table_from_file(sb, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
```

So my work-around is this monstrosity that doubles the amount of memory used:

```py
with io.StringIO() as sb:
    csv.writer(sb).writerows(rows)
    sb.flush()
    sb.seek(0)
    with io.BytesIO(sb.getvalue().encode('utf-8')) as buffer:
        job = bq.load_table_from_file(buffer, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
```

Somewhere in this chain there *must* be a way to specify the byte-encoding so that readers of the file-like `sb` will see the data as UTF-8. Or is there a way to use `csv.writer()` with a byte stream?

I've looked for both of these answers on StackOverflow but what I've found has generally been for writing to files and for stuff in memory everything points to `StringIO`.

Comment: There must be a way to create the job directly from the `rows`. Otherwise the whole thing would be inefficient not only in terms of memory usage but also in terms of CPU usage since encoding characters in bytes and back again is quite expensive.

Comment: Well, creating a job requires contacting the API service which means the `rows` must be serialized into a transport format such as JSON or CSV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `TextIOWrapper` class which does the job but if you use a context manager `with` it then it will *close* the stream and make the original `BytesIO` object unusable.

Modifying my original example:

```py
with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
    sb = io.TextIOWrapper(buffer, 'utf-8', newline='')
    csv.writer(sb).writerows(rows)
    sb.flush()
    buffer.seek(0)
    job = bq.load_table_from_file(buffer, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
```

Another caveat is the `newline` parameter which, if left alone, does translations of new-line characters. Set `newline = ''` to prevent this.

Comment: I don't think it's the context manager that's closing the stream, its the csv writer when it goes out of scope - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48434568

Comment: The `TextIOWrapper` actually closes the stream when _it_ goes out of scope (the `csv.writer` does not close the stream). There is a `detach()` method to avoid this behavior - an unfortunate design that requires saving references to TextIOWrapper even when all you need is a temporary pass-through of string to bytes